What's the difference between `Hello` and `Hello there`?
What's the meaning of there of Hello there?
I often see it used
Hello there!

as opening words,
what's the difference between Hello and Hello there?

"Hello" is a common greeting. Perhaps the most common in English.
The addition of 'there' can be for a few reasons. Primarily, it makes the greeting into a callout to someone to get their attention - you could take it to mean "you over there!". However, you will also find that people who are already acquainted say it upon a chance meeting after recognition has been made, just as an acknowledgement of the surprise nature of the meeting.
There are surely countless examples of the phrase in media, but "hello there" has become something of a trope in the Star Wars franchise for the character Obi-Wan Kenobi. In the original 1977 movie, he called out "hello there" to get the attention of R2D2 who was in the near distance. The character said it again in Episode III, sarcastically, upon catching some enemies by surprise, causing them to turn around. Since then the line has been used in a rather unusual, non-idiomatic way, which seems like lazy writing and an attempt to turn it into a catchphrase for the character. So, not every example you see in media may match the normal use by native speakers.


Hello there!

Sometimes this form can be used to indicate pleasant surprise to have encountered the person on a walk. It's somewhat dated in American English. I don't hear the nation's youth using it.
It can also be a way of hailing someone, an attempt to get their attention.

Hello there! I hope you're going to clean up after your dog. I am planning to mow the grass on the verge next to the sidewalk today. In the future, I'd rather you let your dog empty its bowels somewhere else — perhaps on your own lawn.

Hello! can serve those same functions with the appropriate intonation, but the "there" of Hello there! reinforces those meanings.

It's also something you will hear at a Disney theme park from one of the character actors when greeting a child "Well, hello there, what's your name?" As you say, slightly antiquated (1950's AmE?)

@PeterJennings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyPzTqTOWhE&t=36s
